# How to make both javac and java on my path in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: path, ubuntu-16.04, java

I need to make both javac and java on my path. 
I used the commands I got from other sites

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

Now provided all of these information, how can I set the path? I am comfortable using `vi ~/.bashrc`. So please guide me step by step for the setup. I found other posts very confusing.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451261/adding-java-home-jdk-in-bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo vim .bashrc

(Check this path "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle" if jvm installed their)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle


export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

save it.

run

```
bash
```

> or

```
source .bashrc
```